# How to use Amcharts4 in angular6?

Tags: javascript, charts, angular6, amcharts

I am implementing [amcharts4](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4) "Animated-Gauge" demo in angular6 project.

Here is my code:

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enwsmh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

It is working fine on StackBlitz online editor but throwing an error when i am implementing in my angular6 project. It is throwing an error warning at line number 25 which is this

```
var axis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
```

And it is throwing this error when i hover on line number 25 error.

```
Argument of type 'ValueAxis<AxisRenderer> is not assignable to parameter'
of type Axis<AxisRendererCircular>
```

Here is my error image:

[image]

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Please post code as text rather than in image

Comment: I mentioned StackBlitz link . You can find all the code there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sometimes you need to give hints to the typescript compiler so it knows what axis type you're using for gauge charts. Try modifying the new value axis instantiation to:

```
chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis<am4charts.AxisRendererCircular>());
```

If you run into a similar error for the gauge chart's category axis (if you have one), use

```
chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis<am4charts.AxisRendererRadial>());
```

Also make sure you have TypeScript >= 2.8.1 for your local project (stackblitz is using 3.1.1) and make sure you have the following lines in your tsconfig.json as documented [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/getting-started/using-typescript-or-es6/#TypeScript_strict_mode)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "strictFunctionTypes": false
  }
}
```

Comment: In one case, I needed to type the left-hand side like this `const categoryAxis: CategoryAxis<AxisRendererCircular> = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());`

Answer (score 1):

just change the line 23 by adding `as any`

```
 let chart  = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.GaugeChart) as any;
```

Answer (score -3):

Go to your line No. 25 and just replace this line.

var axis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis():any);

Actually the problem is, you are not declaring the data type

assign the type 'any'. It will work and you will not get the error anymore

Comment: Can you add more context to this answer please?